# Is it something wrong? my nested route not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Here is my code:

```
    import './App.css';
    import React from 'react';
    import AddCallTree from './components/callTree/AddCallTree';
    import CallTreeList from './components/callTree/CallTreeList';
    import Home from "./components/Home";
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='/callTree' element={<CallTreeList />}>
              <Route path='new' element={<AddCallTree />} />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      );
    }
```

When I browse http://localhost:3000/callTree/new, it still shows the `<CallTreeList />` component content, but not the `<AddCallTree />`.

When I move the following statement:

```
<Route path='new' element={<AddCallTree />} />
```

out of the "callTree" block, and then I browse http://localhost:3000/new, it works!

Would you help to fix the problem?